# Find second derivative of $\gamma (t) = A^{-1}(t)$ where $A: \mathbb{R} \to GL(\mathbb{R}^l)$ is smooth curve.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations

Find second derivative of $\gamma (t) = A^{-1}(t)$ where $A: \mathbb{R} \to GL(\mathbb{R}^l)$ is smooth curve.

What I should get is following
$$\gamma '' = 2 \gamma ' A \gamma ' - A^{-1} \frac{d^2 A}{dt^2} A^{-1}.$$

I have proven that if $f:GL(X) \to GL(X)$ given as $f(L) = L^{-1} $, where $GL(X) := \{ L \in \mathcal{L} (X; X) \mid \exists L^{-1} \in \mathcal{L} (X; X) \} $, first derivative of such a map is
$$Df(A)h = -A^{-1} h A^{-1}.$$

I've tried to do something with that but I was unable to get exactly what is required.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\gamma=f\circ A$. The chain rule then tells us that
$$\gamma'(t)=\mathrm{D}\gamma(t)\cdot 1=(\mathrm{D}f(A(t))\circ\mathrm{D}A(t))\cdot 1=\mathrm{D}f(A(t))\cdot A'(t)=-(A(t))^{-1}A'(t)(A(t))^{-1},$$
hence $\gamma'=-\gamma A'\gamma$. Now, we use the (general) Leibniz rule to find $\gamma''$:
$$\gamma'' = -\gamma'A'\gamma-\gamma A''\gamma-\gamma A'\gamma'.$$
Finally, using that $\gamma'=-\gamma A'\gamma$, we get:
$$\gamma'' = -(-\gamma A'\gamma)A'\gamma-\gamma A''\gamma-\gamma A'(-\gamma A'\gamma) = 2\gamma A'\gamma A'\gamma - \gamma A''\gamma.$$
The equality desired is obtained by observing that $\gamma'A\gamma'=\gamma A'\gamma A'\gamma$ (and using the notation $\gamma=A^{-1}$ and $A''=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2A}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$).